# Does my data fit a nested ANOVA/linear mixed effects model, and how should the formula be written?

Tags: r, nested, formula, lme4, anova

I have a single continuous measurement that I collected from 40 different mice. They were separated into eight enclosures under one of four different light treatments (each treatment was applied in duplicate). My experiment tested two species of mice, both male and female, but these ratios were not equal. I am mainly interested in the differences between light treatments and not between enclosures, though I would eventually like to evaluate that, as well. Would my data be best suited for a nested ANOVA model, or a linear mixed effects model? What should the formula look like?

I know that this cannot be a two-way ANOVA since the subgroups were of unequal sizes. I am not sure what the random variable would be. I believe that the groups are the light treatments, and that the subgroups would be sex and species (and maybe enclosure number?).

Here is what I found online for an "unbalanced two-way ANOVA":

```
model3 <- aov(NSTC ~ Sex*Species*Light, data=NSTC)
Anova(model3, type = "III")
```

And this is a code I found for nested ANOVA that is giving me an error, even though I do specify a random effect term ("No random effects terms specified in formula")

```
model4 = lmer(NSTC ~ Light+Species+Sex, random=~1|ID, 
            data=NSTC, 
            REML=T)
```

I expect that my data will show very little significance, but I am basically seeing none from the code I have tried thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your lmer model "not having a random effects" is because you have the syntax wrong for that function.

it should be:

```
model4 = lmer(NSTC ~ Light+Species+Sex+(1|ID), 
        data=NSTC, 
        REML=T)
```

To include the enclosures as random effects, and ID nested within:

```
model4 = lmer(NSTC ~ Light+Species+Sex+(1|Enclosure/ID), 
        data=NSTC, 
        REML=T)
```

That is assuming that each mouse `ID` was only in 1 enclosure each. If each mouse `ID` visited every enclosure, then you probably want to cross them:

```
model4 = lmer(NSTC ~ Light+Species+Sex+(1|ID)+(1|Enclosure), 
        data=NSTC, 
        REML=T)
```

See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified for more details on crossed vs nested random effects.

Also, note that there are interaction terms available to you as well. 
For example, if you are interested in how the different species respond to light, the interaction between those two fixed effects is written `Light:Species`, which you would add as its own input like:

```
model4 = lmer(NSTC ~ Light+Species+Sex+Light:Species+(1|Enclosure/ID), 
        data=NSTC, REML=T)
```

Although the `*` symbol is a shortcut to get each term on their own + the interaction.
So, `Light+Species+Light:Species` is the same as `Light*Species`, which is much simpler:

```
model4 = lmer(NSTC ~ Light*Species+Sex+(1|Enclosure/ID), 
        data=NSTC, REML=T)
```

This document is of good general `lme4` help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was so helpful, I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: If I have answered your question thoroughly enough, you can mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking on the checkmark. Doing this may help other people avoid answering a question (this one particularly) that has already been answered.